# Multiple Line graphs combine to one cummulative graph SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012, linegraph, cumulative-line-chart

[This is what my Graph currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKE7k.png)

I am working on a Graph in SSRS and that consists of a bar chart and a line graph. My bar graph seems to be working perfectly fine, however my line chart has provided me with multiple line charts. Can i get some help on how to make the 7 line graphs that are showing in my report into 1 cumulative line graph.

[Design View of the Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQBJO.png)

Comment: A pic of your design view as well as the expression for the line chart value would help. Is your bar chart a different chart? From your question, I thought you were combining them on one chart.

Comment: So thers 2 charts, a bar chart and a line graph. The bar chart is fine but it is the line graph that i need help with. The Espression i have used is: =RunningValue(SUM(IIF(Fields!Cost_Type.Value = "Actual Costs" AND Fields!Start_Date.Value <= Parameters!StartMonth.Value AND Fields!FY.Value = Parameters!StartFY.Value, Cdbl(Fields!Cost.Value), IIF(Fields!Cost_Type.Value = "Estimate to Complete" AND Fields!Start_Date.Value > Parameters!StartMonth.Value  AND Fields!FY.Value = Parameters!StartFY.Value, Cdbl(Fields!Cost.Value) ,0))), Sum, Nothing).

Comment: Its a little complicated but basically says if the cost type is actual cost and the start date is within the current financial year (which is a parameter) then show values, and if the estimate to complete is also within the current financial year then show values otherwise dont show anything. I have included a photo of the design view in the previous post. @HannoverFist

Comment: It looks like you have a **series group** in your chart for **Portfolio**. I assume that you are using this for the bar chart and don't want to remove it but the only way I see to make this work is to remove the series and emulate it in with multiple bar charts using **IIF*** statements in your **Values** ( `=SUM(IIF(Fields!Portfolio.value = "Text A", Fields!Cost.Value, NOTHING)) ` ). Unfortunately this would have to be hard coded and not dynamic.